# Why is this Django form not raising ValidationError?

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to raise a ValidationError during registration if a use with the same email already exists. I have added the following method in my form to do that.

```
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')

        if email:
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(email=email)
            except:
                user = None
        if user is not None:
            raise forms.ValidationError('This email address is unavailable!')

        return email
```

However, I have included a print statement after `except` and the console always prints that value. So it is for some reason executing that part of the code even if the user with the specified email address exists.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `return email` with error contents...

Comment: I didn't understand. Sorry.

Comment: @MiniGunnR Did you import User model as I suggested..??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in return fuction, in the place of try ,except just use exists() method for code simplification :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')

    if email:
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('This email address is unavailable!')
        else:
            pass

    return email
```

And make sure that html code is also updated like this in your form template :

```
   {% if form.errors %}
        {% for field in form %}
            {% for error in field.errors %}
                <div class="row">
                    {{ error|escape }}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
            <div class="row">
                {{ error|escape }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: I am getting `'str' object has no attribute 'objects'`. This line is highlighted `if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():`.

Comment: @MiniGunnR Did you import User model into your forms.py file?? If not,then import User model.

Comment: @MiniGunnR You have overriden `User` by a string.

Comment: Hey man. Thanks. I have imported the User model now. It works!